# AppBarLayout wrongfully adds the statusbar height to its own height with fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, fresco

**The setup**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/poi_detail_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.varese.PoiActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/poi_detail_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/poi_detail_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/poi_detail_toolbar">

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/poi_detail_header_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:viewAspectRatio="1.43" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/poi_detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_poi" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/poi_detail_app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_audio_play" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The current situation**

[image: Here is how it turn out]

With drawn limits:

[image]

This are the actual heights for the content:

```
 AppBar      height: 827
    Collapsing  height: 827
    HeaderImage height: 755
    Toolbar     height: 168
```

**The problem**

The `AppBar` adds the status bar height to its height, resulting in an `AppBar` that is slightly longer than needed, showing the red bar below the `HeaderImage`. So basically I'm expecting a height of 755 (on this phone), but I get `755 (HeaderImage's height) + 72 (Statusbar's height)`.
HeaderImage is a `SimpleDraweeView` (from [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-simpledraweeview.html)) with aspectRatio of 1.43, so it's setting its own height dynamically (based on width) and I can't hardcode the AppBar's height.

I don't think this is an expected behavior, but maybe I'm just missing something in the `fitsSystemWindows` recipe.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with this problem. Please mark with a star this bug on bugtracker here to make google fix this bug:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75707002